# Why link is not working which was in under list

Tags: html, css

```html
<ul class="social-media-list">
  <li class="tw">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="contact-icon ">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="fb">
    <a href="https://www.facebook" target="_blank" class="contact-icon ">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i>
    </i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="ln">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="contact-icon ">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ig">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="contact-icon ">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These icons can be found in the footer of my website. Nothing happens when I put the link to the href and click the icon on the web page. It's not error in the link . But when I create a normal anchor tag and use that link, it will work. Is that the issue with this under on the list items? Could someone please explain the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For starters, your HTML is malformed.  Additionally, your URLs are incomplete.  Aside from that, it's not clear to me what you mean.  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have missed ".com" in url to which it should be redirected in href.